# How to filter and add multiple datasets using Django and Chart.js

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I've been scratching my head for quite a while on this so any help is much appreciated.

Let's say I have a model called Transaction.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.Cascade)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to generate a chart using chart.js.
So far i am able to do this for all the objects using this JS:

```
<script>
 $(function () {
var $xChart = $("#xChart");
$.ajax({
  url: $xChart.data("url"),
  success: function (data) {
    var ctx = $xChart[0].getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'xChart'
        }
      }
    });

  }
});
  });

</script>
```

And this FBV for the ajax call:

```
def x_chart(request):
  def random_color():
    return "#"+''.join([choice('ABCDEF0123456789') for i in range(6)])
  labels=[]
  data=[]
  enddate = datetime.now()
  startdate = datetime.now().date() - relativedelta(days=3)

  transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(time__range=[startdate,enddate])

  grouped_transactions = transactions.values("time__day").annotate(total=Sum('value'))
  for key in grouped_transactions:
    labels.append(key['time__day'])
    data.append(key['total'])    
    
  return JsonResponse(
    data={
        'labels': labels,
        'datasets': [
            {
          'label': 'All Transactions,
          'backgroundColor': str(random_color()),
          'data': data,
            }
        ],          
    }
)
```

I want to create a dataset from each Transaction.client field and then pass it as Json to the ajax request. How would i be able to do that since the lables are the dates and some clients don't have transactions in certain dates but some do.
Thanks

Comment: Kudos for tackling charts.js and django!  Question: what does the x_chart view do?  I'm guessing the intent is to refresh the data of a given chart on a page?  This may be relevant, since there are different ways to approach the solution.

Comment: Yes, i have another function for rendering the html. I didn't add that function to keep the post short. 
The purpose of the xchart is to return the Json data for chartjs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  In your place, I might consider approaching this a little differently:  For example, instead of trying to pass the chart's configuration as JSON to the existing template, you could break out the chart as its own HTML file, with the chart, and chart scripts.  Then use your view to build the variables you want to pass as context, render the chart template with "render_to_string" and use AJAX to refresh the chart on your page.  The key idea here is to keep the chart config on the front end, and the variables in the view.  Let me know if any of that makes sense, or not! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the user in your filter. Use `request.user`.

```
def x_chart(request):
  def random_color():
    return "#"+''.join([choice('ABCDEF0123456789') for i in range(6)])
  labels=[]
  data=[]
  enddate = datetime.now()
  startdate = datetime.now().date() - relativedelta(days=3)
  the_client = request.user
  transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(client=the_client,time__range=[startdate,enddate])

  grouped_transactions = transactions.values("time__day").annotate(total=Sum('value'))
  for key in grouped_transactions:
    labels.append(key['time__day'])
    data.append(key['total'])    
    
  return JsonResponse(
    data={
        'labels': labels,
        'datasets': [
            {
          'label': 'All Transactions,
          'backgroundColor': str(random_color()),
          'data': data,
            }
        ],          
    }
)
```